# Claim Based Authentication user LoginName and People Picker problem

Tags: claims-based-auth, people-picker, claim-provider

I have a problem with People Picker in my claim based app:

- From People Picker finds many instance of the same user
- From Code EnsureUser(Domain\Name) doesn't work at all
- From Code EnsureUser(email) works sometimes..

I've read online that I must write down a new people picker but online I find only examples which adds claims to customize people picker and not to modify it to work as expected..

Does anyone has some suggestion about a people picker to install on my farm which works with Login names like Windows Auth?

Another problem in claim based:

Web.CurrentUser IS NULL!

Any suggestion to get current user? 
I tried with

```
Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.User
```

but I obtain only a code like S-1-5-17